# Dynamic variable in attributes seen as undefined

Tags: vue.js, pug

I have 2 vue components. A parent component:  `list of services` who store many `service` component.

> Service.vue

```
<template lang="pug">
  a.list-group-item.list-group-item(id='list-' + name + '-list' data-toggle="list" href="#list-" + name role="tab" aria-controls=name) {{ name }}
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    name: String,
    description: String
  }
}
</script>
```

> List.vue

```
<template lang="pug">
  section.border-bottom.border-warning
    .container(style="background-color: #EA846F")
      .text-white.text-center.title Serviciile oferite
    .list-group#list-tab(v-if="response.status === 200" role="tablist")
      service(v-for="service in response.data" :name="service.name" :description="service.description")
    .h5.text-muted.text-center(v-else) {{ response.statusText }}
</template>

<script>
import service from './service';

import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      response: {},
    }
  },
  components: {
    service
  },
  methods: {
    async getAll() {
      this.response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/infos');
    }
  },
  async mounted() {
    await this.getAll();
  }
```

Why `name` sended as prop and used in service template is `undefined`? How can I fix this ?

Comment: most times its just `undefined` because it is `undefined` - did you debug your response?

Comment: @Estradiaz `{{ name }}` from the end of a tag return expected value

Comment: so what is your issue - you are not using `"name"`anywhere else?

Comment: the issue is: the attributes of a tag like href `href="#list-" + name` returns me `#list-undefined` instead name value.

Comment: Making your `mounted` lifecycle hook `async` won't accomplish anything. Vue will not wait for it to complete. You might as well have `mounted() { this.getAll() }`

Comment: but name is undefined as it is not referenced from prop - its accessing a name variable in pug not in vue - you parse pug into vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Pug at all but it would seem you need to use `v-bind` syntax as you would anywhere else you want to interpolate props or data within attribute values

```
a.list-group-item.list-group-item(:id="`list${name}-list`" :href="`#list-${name}`" data-toggle="list"  role="tab" aria-controls=name) {{ name }}
```

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Using-JavaScript-Expressions

I've used [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) but you could also revert to concatenation, eg

```
a(:id="'list' + name + '-list'" ...
```

---

I would also, at the very least initialise `response` to have an empty `data` array so you're not trying to iterate `undefined` on initial display, ie

```js
return {
  response: {
    data: []
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That was. The attributes had to be binded to the tag.
Small observation: I had to use full syntax `v-bind:href` etc. just `:href` throw me an error

Comment: @dem.1797 that seems odd since you're using the `v-bind` shorthand syntax in your `service` element